# How to prove the divergence theorem for two improper integrals?

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

I'm having trouble with this proof, can anyone please help me out?

If $\int_{a}^{\infty}f(x) dx$ diverges and $0 \le f(x) \le g(x)$ for all $ x\in[a, \infty)$, then $\int_{a}^{\infty}g(x)dx$ also diverges.

$0 \le f(x) \le g(x)$

$\int_{a}^{\infty} 0 dx \le \int_{a}^{\infty}f(x) dx \le \int_{a}^{\infty}g(x)dx$

$ 0 \le \lim_{A\to \infty}\int_{a}^{A}(f(x) \le g(x)) dx$

$\lim_{A\to \infty}(f(A)-f(a) \le g(A)-g(a))$

Answer (score 0):

This is not true: $0\leq g(x)\leq 1$, $x\in[1,\infty)$, $g(x)=1/x^{2}$ but $\displaystyle\int_{1}^{\infty}g(x)dx<\infty$ and of course $\displaystyle\int_{1}^{\infty}1dx=\infty$.

But the following is true: $0\leq f(x)\leq g(x)$, $x\in[a,\infty)$ and $\displaystyle\int_{a}^{\infty}f(x)dx$ diverges, then so is $\displaystyle\int_{a}^{\infty}g(x)dx$:

Because we know that $\lim_{M\rightarrow\infty}\displaystyle\int_{a}^{M}g(x)dx=\sup_{M\geq a}\int_{a}^{M}g(x)dx$, if $\displaystyle\int_{a}^{\infty}g(x)dx$ converges, which means that the limit exists, then $\displaystyle\int_{a}^{M}f(x)dx\leq\int_{a}^{M}g(x)dx\leq\sup_{M\geq a}\int_{a}^{M}g(x)dx$, then $\sup_{M\geq a}\displaystyle\int_{a}^{M}f(x)dx\leq\sup_{M\geq a}\int_{a}^{M}g(x)dx<\infty$, so $\lim_{M\rightarrow\infty}\displaystyle\int_{a}^{M}f(x)dx=\sup_{M\geq a}\int_{a}^{M}f(x)dx<\infty$, which means that $\displaystyle\int_{a}^{\infty}f(x)dx$ converges, a contradiction.

Comment: the theorem is f(x) less than or equal to g(x)

Comment: Then you just had a very crucial typo.

Comment: Ok I fixed it. Can you see it?

Comment: It's $0 \le f(x) \le g(x)$ now

Comment: Why are we taking the supremum?

Comment: Do you know that for a nonnegative function $f$, $\displaystyle\int_{a}^{\infty}f(x)dx$ must exist, in the sense that either it is finite or infinite, and the value is just the supremum.

Comment: So then why aren't we taking the supremum of f then?

Comment: Of course you can take it, but taking it initially cannot conclude anything.

Comment: So then how do we know that taking it for g would conclude something?

Comment: Did you read throughout my proof? If so, then it is clear why we start with $g$.

Comment: I'm confused. How does it equal the supremum if it converges?

Comment: Because the function is nonnegative, and $M\rightarrow\displaystyle\int_{a}^{M}f(x)dx$ is increasing for $M\geq a$.

Comment: So if it exists, we are taking the supremeum of both functions?

Comment: Only for those nonnegative functions.

Comment: M is infinity and a is any positive number right?

Comment: Also, if the contradiction is true, then doesn't that mean the theorem is false?

Answer (score 0):

You can take the contrapositive of this statement to prove it, because of the fact following fact: Let P and Q be two sentences, such that P $\implies$ Q. This is equivalent to say $\neg$ (Q) $\implies$ $\neg$ (P). So now, you accept that the function g(x) converges in a defined interval - of course, supposing that 0 $\leq$ f(x) $\leq$ g(x) in that interval - and you use this to  prove that f(x) also converges in that interval. The proof isn't long, but you have to use some basic properties of intergrals. Hope this will help you.